# What does Banishment do to a person Polymorphed into an outsider?

Tags: dnd-5e, polymorph

If a person is Polymorphed into an outsider by the 4th level spell *Polymorph*, what affect does the 4th level spell *Banishment* have on them?

I mean, based on RAW, they're treated as a native, because they started that way, but I think it has interesting consequences to treat it the other way?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I was referring to the fourth level spell, which I now see as being only able to turn people into beasts. I apologize for the lack of details in the question. It was a hypothetical situation that Happened in a dream from last night and wanted to get it down before I forgot.

Comment: Why not use Plane Shift, for the same effect? Alternatively, Polymorph into a Sea Horse (Cha mod: -4), pick it up from the ground, and Plane Shift.

Answer (score 10):

According to the Polymorph spell you are limited to 'beasts'. Which means you wouldn't be able to change them into an outsider.

If you are talking about True Polymorph, then yes, they actually do change into an outsider because they gain all of the target forms statistics. This means it is in fact native to another plane. It also means the Banishment spell would work and have the permanent effect.

Of course its all up to the DM whether this works, but you would be expending a 9th and 4th level spell slot, so it wouldn't be all that overpowered.